# Making a 4 sided Graph / 4 sided (Cartesian) grid In Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, graph, charts, axis

I've been trying to make a 4 sided graph  / 4 sided grid that can show and connect points that I set

However using the Chart in the toolbox did not work as I couldn't find that type of a graph. How can I make one?

Example graph:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is quite simple. All you need to do is tell the `Chart` to place the `Crossing` of the `Axis` at certain points, instead of keeping it unset (`NaN`).

You also should set the range by setting `Minimum` and `Maximum`:
[image]

```
ChartArea CA = chart1.ChartAreas[0];
Series S1 = chart1.Series[0];
S1.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;

CA.AxisX.Maximum = 100;
CA.AxisX.Minimum = -100;
CA.AxisY.Maximum = 100;
CA.AxisY.Minimum = -100;

CA.AxisX.Crossing = 0;
CA.AxisY.Crossing = 0;

CA.AxisX.Interval = 10;
CA.AxisY.Interval = 10;

CA.AxisX.LineWidth = 3;
CA.AxisY.LineWidth = 3;

CA.AxisX.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
CA.AxisY.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
CA.AxisX.MinorTickMark.Enabled = false;
CA.AxisY.MinorTickMark.Enabled = false;


// now we add a few points:
S1.Points.AddXY(-21,81);
S1.Points.AddXY(52,60);
S1.Points.AddXY(-53, -11);
S1.Points.AddXY(-53, 88);
```

You can use most chart types, though not all, like Pie.

You can play around with many other properties to make it work as you want; especially the `Interval` may be of interest!

Other properies of interest include these:

```
CA.AxisX.ArrowStyle = AxisArrowStyle.Triangle;
CA.AxisX.MinorTickMark.Enabled = false;    
CA.AxisX.LabelStyle.Enabled = false;
```

Comment: You may want to have a look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36119477/nicer-axisarrowstyle-arrows/36119485#36119485), inspired by your question!