# Nicer AxisArrowStyle arrows for my Chart.Axes

Tags: c#, charts, axis

I answered a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36117364/making-a-4-sided-graph-4-sided-grid-in-visual-studio/36117836#36117836) on how to set up a `Chart` to look like a regular mathematical graph, i.e. with the axes centered and with nice arrows to the top and to the right..

However I found the built-in [AxisArrowStyle.Triangle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.axisarrowstyle%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to be rather big and found no way to make it smaller.

> Lines -             A line-shaped arrow is used for the relevant axis.
>
> None -          No arrow is used for the relevant axis.
>
> SharpTriangle -     A sharp triangular arrow is used for the relevant axis.
>
> Triangle -      A triangular arrow is used for the relevant axis.

Here is the original look of it:

[image]

So how can we fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Chart's `axis.AxisArrowStyle` enumeration doesn't let us pick a smaller arrow, only a slimmer one.

So we need to draw it ourselves:

[image]

Here is a simple but effective piece of code that achieves just that:

```
private void chart1_PrePaint(object sender, ChartPaintEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ChartElement.ToString().StartsWith("ChartArea-") )
    {
        // get the positions of the axes' ends:
        ChartArea CA = chart1.ChartAreas[0];
        float xx = (float)CA.AxisX.ValueToPixelPosition(CA.AxisX.Maximum);
        float xy = (float)CA.AxisY.ValueToPixelPosition(CA.AxisY.Crossing);
        float yx = (float)CA.AxisX.ValueToPixelPosition(CA.AxisX.Crossing);
        float yy = (float)CA.AxisY.ValueToPixelPosition(CA.AxisY.Maximum);

        // a simple arrowhead geometry:
        int arrowSize = 18;   // size in pixels
        Point[] arrowPoints = new Point[3]   { new Point(-arrowSize, -arrowSize / 2), 
             new Point(-arrowSize, arrowSize / 2), Point.Empty };

        // draw the two arrows by moving and/or rotating the graphics object:
        e.ChartGraphics.Graphics.TranslateTransform(xx + arrowSize, xy);
        e.ChartGraphics.Graphics.FillPolygon(Brushes.Black, arrowPoints);
        e.ChartGraphics.Graphics.TranslateTransform(yx -xx -arrowSize, yy -xy -arrowSize);
        e.ChartGraphics.Graphics.RotateTransform(-90);
        e.ChartGraphics.Graphics.FillPolygon(Brushes.Black, arrowPoints);
        e.ChartGraphics.Graphics.ResetTransform();
    }
}
```