# WinForms: highlighting X and Y axes

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, mschart

I'm making a program to graph parabolas, and I want to make the X and Y axes (the ones from (0,0)) a different color. I haven't found any options to do so, and the only solution I've found is to make a large grid and set its increment to half the graph's size. Is there an alternative?

I used the default chart control. I'd expect something like:

[image]

Comment: How do you create the graph? Using GDI+ and custom painting or using MSChart or something else? Please add more details to the question. Also adding some code or an image of what you expect may be helpful.

Comment: I used the default chart control. I'd expect something like http://mathbits.com/MathBits/StudentResources/GraphPaper/14by14%20axes.jpg

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Making a 4 sided Graph / 4 sided grid In Visual Studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36117364/making-a-4-sided-graph-4-sided-grid-in-visual-studio) - Also have a look [at this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36119477/nicer-axisarrowstyle-arrows-for-my-chart-axes/36119485#36119485)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set [`Crossing`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.datavisualization.charting.axis.crossing(v=vs.110).aspx) for axis to move the axis to center of chart. Also you can set [`LineWidth`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.datavisualization.charting.axis.linewidth(v=vs.110).aspx) for axis to make it thicker. Also you can set [`ArrowStyle`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.datavisualization.charting.axis.arrowstyle(v=vs.110).aspx) to have an arrow at the end of axis.

For example, to have a chart like this:

[image]

Use such code:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Set Chart Margins
    this.chart1.ChartAreas[0].Position.Auto = false;
    this.chart1.ChartAreas[0].Position.X = 10;
    this.chart1.ChartAreas[0].Position.Y = 10;
    this.chart1.ChartAreas[0].Position.Width = 80;
    this.chart1.ChartAreas[0].Position.Height = 80;

    //Configure X Axis
    this.chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Crossing = 0;
    this.chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Interval = 1;
    this.chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Enabled = false;
    this.chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LineWidth = 2;
    this.chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ArrowStyle =
        System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.AxisArrowStyle.Lines;

    //Configure Y Axis
    this.chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Crossing = 0;
    this.chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Interval = 5;
    this.chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.LineWidth = 2;
    this.chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.LabelStyle.Enabled = false;
    this.chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.ArrowStyle =
        System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.AxisArrowStyle.Lines;

    //Set Chart Type
    this.chart1.Series[0].ChartType = 
        System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Spline;

    //Set Data
    var p = new List<PointF>();
    for (int i = -5; i <= 5; i++)
    {
        p.Add(new PointF(i, i * Math.Abs(i)));
    }
    this.chart1.DataSource = p;
    this.chart1.Series[0].XValueMember = "X";
    this.chart1.Series[0].YValueMembers = "Y";
    this.chart1.Series[0].IsVisibleInLegend = false;
}
```