# Can we draw Tertiary Y Axis with the use of chart control

Tags: c#, winforms, charts

I want to draw a graph which has 2 different Y axis with one X Axis. Can we take different Y axis for different series? In first series I want candlestick graph and in second column chart, both charts should be in same chart area and should not be mixed with each other.

For example you can see the picture below

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `ChartArea`  can have **two** x-axes and **two** y-axes.

The secondary axes are called

```
 chartArea.AxisX2
```

and

```
 chartArea.AxisY2
```

Enable them like this:

```
  chartArea.AxisY2.Enabled = AxisEnabled.True;
```

Now you can style them as usual..

You can relate a `Series` to one of the `Axes` by setting the `AxisType` like this:

```
 yourSeries.YAxisType = AxisType.Secondary;
```

Talking about axes: It is worth knowing that you can move them relative to each other by setting their `Crossing`; see [here for an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36117364/making-a-4-sided-graph-4-sided-grid-in-visual-studio/36117836#36117836)..

Comment: If I add  chartArea.AxisY2.Enabled = AxisEnabled.True; line so is it going to show proper output?? As I want.

Comment: It is like secondary Y axis which comes at right side. Can we split primary Y axis for different series?

Comment: I don't know how to do either of that in one chartarea. Why not use two if you want this? They can be aligned to make them look like one.. Other than that, you __can__ create all the labels on __one__ y-axis as customlabels yourself and make them show whatever you want...