# Drawing polygons on the canvas

Tags: c#, .net, graphics

I'm create a desktop application using MVVM.
I'm accept certain data, after which on their basis I draw models, which are polygons.
I want to represent these polygons on a coordinate plane that has visible axes and gridlines. 
I'm not sure that this can be done with the help of Graphics.DrawPolygon on the canvas, so can you suggest libraries that can help me?

Comment: You will have to draw the axes and gridlines yourself. Not harder than a few DrawLine calls. You __could__ use a [MSChart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36117364/making-a-4-sided-graph-4-sided-cartesian-grid-in-visual-studio/36117836#36117836), move the axes to the center and draw in the PostPaint event but it will take away some control from the axes styling. - Asking for libraries is off-topic here btw!

Comment: I guess you can create a user control that exposes an ObservableCollection of your polygon points that is databound which will get redrawn whenever the collection changes. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: IME it's quicker to write graphics code to draw gridlines and things yourself than it is to work out how to use a chart library, unless they have an example that does exactly what you want. C#'s graphics functions are pretty good.