# How to show only one dashed line for Y axis at center in Microsoft chart controls?

Tags: c#, mschart

I want to display a single dashed line along Y-axis positioned at the middle vertically. I thought of it as a trivial problem but it seems that either I don't know how to do it or it is not available as a direct option.

This is what I've tried so far

```
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Enabled = AxisEnabled.True;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.LineWidth = 1;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.MajorGrid.Enabled = true;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.MinorGrid.Enabled = false;

chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.IsStartedFromZero = true;

chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.MajorGrid.IntervalType = DateTimeIntervalType.Number;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.MajorGrid.IntervalOffsetType = DateTimeIntervalType.Number;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.MajorGrid.Interval = 5;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Interval = 5;    

chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.MajorGrid.LineColor = Color.Black;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.MajorGrid.LineDashStyle = ChartDashStyle.Dash;
```

Note that I know interval property is not set according to what I want but the problem is no matter what value I set for chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Interval property chart control simply draws so many lines along Y-axis. I'd even tried normalizing my input to the range [-50, 50] and rounded them to integers but still the results are same. However, my logic of interval is working with X-axis and yielding expected results but not for Y-axes.

Comment: I don't know just what you want. Do you want to change style or position of the Y-axis? Or do you want to add a line somewhere? Where? Maybe you should simply turn off the gridlines and set the y-axis Crossing property to the 'middle value'?

Comment: [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36117364/making-a-4-sided-graph-4-sided-cartesian-grid-in-visual-studio/36117836?r=SearchResults&s=3|33.2570#36117836)

Comment: @TaW thank you! example link above helped. I wanted a line in the middle similar to the example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I got the solution based on the [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36117364/making-a-4-sided-graph-4-sided-cartesian-grid-in-visual-studio/36117836?r=SearchResults&s=3%7C33.2570#36117836) provided by TaW. Pasting here the example code I used, may it help someone.

```
ChartArea CA = chart1.ChartAreas[0];
        Series S1 = chart1.Series[0];
        S1.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
        CA.AxisY.Maximum = 100;
        CA.AxisY.Minimum = -100;

        CA.AxisY.Crossing = 0;

        CA.AxisY.Interval = 10;

        CA.AxisY.LineWidth = 1;

        CA.AxisY.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
        CA.AxisY.MinorTickMark.Enabled = false;
```

The trick was to disable gridlines and show a line at the middle by setting Crossing = 0 as suggested by TaW. Note that it's only for Y-axis if anyone wants to have it for both axis than need to apply the same properties to X-axis.